# Use Maven to compile multiple JARs during build

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I have some (trivially small) classes I'd like to compile to JARs during a Maven build, so that these JARs can be used when testing the application (the application loads JAR files, they are purely for test purposes).

I've got something working but I'm struggling to adjust the name of the final JAR files which makes me think I'm going down the wrong route.

Take the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <compileSourceRoots>${project.basedir}/ClassDir</compileSourceRoots>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/CompiledClassDir</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/CompiledClassDir</testClassesDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/CompiledJARDir</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- <finalName>MyJar</finalName> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

During the `test-compile` phase, this will compile everything in `ClassDir`, and then package that into a JAR file in `target/CompiledJARDir`.

By default, this is producing an artifact with name `my-artifact-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar` - which is pretty cumbersome as whenever the version of the artifact changes, all the test references that load that JAR need to change.

Using the (undocumented) `finalName` parameter, I'm able to control it a little (e.g. to produce `MyJar-tests.jar`, but a warning is produced as `finalName` isn't supposed to be dynamic. I *think* that this property is actually affecting the final name of the project as a whole, rather than being specific to this `execution`.

Is there another way to adjust the name of the `maven-jar-plugin`? Or another way to compile a JAR?

I think the most Maven-centric approach to my problem is probably have submodules for each of the JARs I want to compile, but I'm unsure how to bind those submodules to the `test-compile` phase so that they are fully-packaged before any tests in `my-artifact` run.

Comment: Create a multi module build which has multiple of those test jar which are produces like any other jar with Maven no special configuration etc.. In your area where to test those parts you can simply add them as a test-scoped dependency... and let them being copied via maven-dependency-plugin into the default directory where you application can load them... also defining them as a dependency of your project it's automatically guaranteed to be built before you test part is being executed... ?

Comment: Furthermore the `finalName` is not undocumented. Simply it should not being used on the level of the jar plugin because it does not really make sense.. You can use the `finalName` on the project level (https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) but in the end it does not make sense, because the name is defined by the artifactId and the version...

Comment: A change in finalName only change it for the `target` directory...In older versions of the maven-jar-plugin you could change that (https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-jar-plugin-2.6/jar-mojo.html) and that is the reason why it's in there... but since 3.0.0 it is a read only part (https://github.com/apache/maven-jar-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/jar/AbstractJarMojo.java#L79)